# Using jQuery to get several responses from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to show on screen a text-based description of what a PHP script is doing. e.g. trigger the function and then the PHP script starts. The user then sees "Step 1 started" ... and then after a few seconds "Step 2 started" .. and so on. There could be hundreds of steps and I would like the user to see what is happening.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "do.php",
          success: function( html ) {
              $("#results").append(html);
              return false;
          }
        });
    });
});
```

And then my PHP (illustrating the problem, my actual code does a lot of work):

```
echo "step 1 done";
sleep(2);
echo "step 2 done";
sleep(2);
echo "step 3 done";
```

At the moment the "result" div just shows "step 1 donestep 2 donestep 3 done" all in one go after 4 seconds. I would like it to show "step 1 done" and then after 2 seconds "step 2 done" and then after another 2 seconds "step 3 done"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous nature of Ajax you'd have to separate the steps in different php files and make multiple `$.ajax` requests within `success` callbacks or better yet, use [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how AJAX works. You are sleeping in your PHP code, and your JavaScript will just wait for a response while it sleeps. As soon as it gets a response, it will execute your function to update the HTML.

If you want to pause in the update of the page HTML, you will probably need use something like JSON to send your response from the PHP page as separate elements, which can then be iterated in the JavaScript. You can then use `setTimeout` to cause pauses in the display of the data that was returned from the PHP page.

Comment: I am not actually sleeping in my production code. I just tried to make the example simple. I just want anything I echo in the PHP code to be shown back on the HTML page in real time.

Comment: That isn't appropriate use for PHP. Check out [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).